# Maven OSGi bundling

Tags: java, osgi

I am using the maven felix plugin to create OSGi bundles, however suppose you have a package "com.example" that exists in project1 and project2. Additionally project2 has a dependency to project1.

If you export the package in project2, it will have the code from project2 **and** from project1. This -to me- is really odd behavior. The only reason I can think of that they enabled such behavior is because OSGi requires it somehow? (I have already looked at http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html but can't seem to find a way to turn it off)

If two jars (A and B) export the same package but different classes in it and a third jar (C) has a dependency to that package, I would assume that C can see both A & B at runtime. Or does OSGi require a different package per jar?

If OSGi is not mandating this, how can I turn this "feature" off?

If OSGi **is** mandating it, then...why?

**UPDATE**

The answer provided by Christian clears up the OSGi requirement for the different packages in different jars. However I still have a problem with felix where I have an "api" jar that contains:

- com.example.api: the actual interfaces
- com.example: a factory class, a utility class,...

And an implementation package that has:

- com.example.impl

Now when I build the implementation package with felix and I export "com.example.impl", it will indeed have everything in "com.example.impl" but for some reason it also includes all the classes in "com.example" (not those in .api). Any combination of settings I have tried will not prevent felix from adding the "base" package for some reason...

So basically in the resulting jar of the "impl" project, I actually have the class com.example.MyFactory which is in the api package. How can I block this?

Answer (score 2):

OSGi is not mandating that you have the same package in two projects. In fact you should avoid to have the same package / version combination in two bundles with different contents.

In OSGi the wiring happens when the bundle goes from installed to resolved. In that step the framework matches each Import-Package statement with an exported package that matches name and version range. In OSGi only one package will be wired to each bundle even if several bundles export the same package. This is different to standard java where you would have a mix of the classes from all jars that have the package which can have quite unpredictable results.

In OSGi there is one pattern where you have the same package in several bundles. It is used for official APIs from OSGi a lot. There when you implement an API you also include the API package and have an Import-Package as well as an Export-Package statement for the API package. This allows the implementing bundle to be installed without the need for an additional API bundle. This works well even if there are more than one bundle that includes the API as the framework will select one of the API packages and wire all others to the same package. So they all see the same set of classes and there is not conflict.

You can also do this for you own applications but there it is more common to just have the API package in one bundle and all others just import it.

You can find some info at the apache felix [OSGi Frequently Asked Questions](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-examples-and-presentations/apache-felix-osgi-faq.html)

---

To answer your updated question. I guess you only export the com.example.api package. So the maven bundle plugin knows it can refer to this package using an Import-Package statement. As com.example is not exported the plugin knowns that an Import-Package would not work. So it embeds the classes.

So what you should take away is that you need to export all packages that are needed by other bundles. Btw. you normally do not export an impl package in OSGi. Rather you hide the impl behind a service. The service interface is placed in API. The impl bundle then implements the interface and exports the impl as an OSGi service. So other bundles can bind the service by its interface and the whole impl can stay private.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it already clears up quite a bit, but I added a more specific usecase that still frustrates me to the original question.